# Magento - Correct Place to store values to be used for attributes

Tags: magento

I have an dropdown attribute that I am creating during my module setup.

I want to pre-populate this attribute with some values while my module is installing.  I can do this no problem, currently by simply storing the values in an array and then creating adding the options to the attribute in the install script.

Where would be the correct place to store these values - in a model?  If so would it be a source model utilizing the toOptionArray method?  This is technically used for forms so it doesnt seem right.  But neither does just storing the values in the setup script.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `toOptionArray` method would be in line with standard Magento practices.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the toOptionArray() is found in Helpers, if that is what you are asking.  Helpers extend far fewer classes, and therefore inherit far fewer methods than models.  This makes them much lighter weight for simple tasks like setting up an array of options, provided that they are static.

If the values are stored in a new DB table, and can be expanded upon by the user, it may make more sense to put this in a Model that has direct access to your DB table.